# start 3DMAX animations in UDK

Tags: game-engine, 3dsmax

I made a shape in 3dmax with a bone and i give it an animation. I export it and imported to UDK. I want that when i shoot to that shape in UDK, my animation started to act. How i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have UDK now, so I can't check it. but I remember, that you have Triggers in UDK. You can use it to detect collision with weapon bullet (TakeDamage) and start animation. There is a link how to do this:

[UDK Forum](http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/873138-Kismet-Trigger-Using-Weapons)

If it is not too clear for you, try to find somwthing more on this forum.